# Why is my ruby loop not ending?

Tags: ruby, loops, error-handling, sdk, break

I am new to ruby!
Here is my code:

```
require 'sdk'

def get_teams_from_evident
   teams_api = SDK::Team.all
   teams = []
   loop do
     teams_api.each do |team|
       puts team.name
       teams << team
     end
     if teams_api.next_page? 
       team_api = teams_api.page(teams_api.next_page_number)
     else
       break
     end
   end
   teams
 end
```

When i run it with

```
$ruby my_script.rb
```

the program never exits, the loop remains hanging...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `team_api` vs `teams_api`

Comment: fixed that and still seeing my program not ending/terminating :(

Comment: What is `teams_api.next_page?` returning? It looks like it's either always `true`, or there's some kind of truthy object being returned.

Comment: `team_api` does not have any use.  Let's check the value of `teams_api.next_page?`

Comment: To be more precise: `teams_api.next_page?` never returns `false` or `nil` - these would be the only values which would break your loop.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have said, the only way your loop can end is if `teams_api.next_page?` returns `false`. If the loop continues to loop for ever, then you can infer that `teams_api.next_page?` *always* returns true. That doesn't seem logical though, your next step should be to check the documentation of `#next_page?`.

That's not the only way your loop can hang though. I've been fooled before, thinking my loop was spinning when in fact a function call inside the loop had frozen. You could add `puts 'loop start'` at the start of the loop to make sure, or you could use a gem like Byebug to step through the code.